# toSVG with Fabric.js exporting background color but not showing in illustrator

Tags: html, canvas, svg, fabricjs, adobe-illustrator

I have implemented canvas with Fabric.js, using toSVG I am getting the canvas data as SVG format. I want to open them in Illustrator or any other editor which is widely uses SVG as ready to print, because the following SVG code exported from canvas is not showing background SVG color in Illustrator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="675" height="450" style="background-color: #f0dac2" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.1.4</desc><defs></defs></svg>
```

First, I am not able to understand, is this a bug or Illustrator have not this kind of functionality. If any editor can open this as a raster image, which is that?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a limitation in Illustrator. Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all show background for me. Mac preview also shows it.

Comment: is there any core file or function where we can make it custom in fabric.js or with any other supportive libraries?